# jQuery autocomplete() submits form, but no values have been sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with one with one link "COUNTRY", by hitting this link, under it appear some other links, which are group of countries. There is also one of the links called "Individual", by hitting that link appears one autocomplete field, where the user can start typing and choose one country.

I want by choosing the country to change some of the hidden fields values and than to submit the form.

The form submission works, but unfortunately there are no POST fields sent.

Here is the HTML & JS code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="news_search_form">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="tAB6ZU6sNafRUNBLiPyhiuCbEDQVGD4waxNbT3Yk">
    <div class="row threelinks">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn_filter_category" data-href="country">
                <div class="links_new link_hover">COUNTRY</div>
            </a>
            <input type="hidden" id="select_country" name="select_country" value="214">
            <input type="hidden" id="filter_country" name="filter_country" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row " style="margin-top: 5px; display: none;" id="country_filters">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="owl-carousel col-md-12">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="filter_link" style="margin: 5px 9px;" data-href="country" data-value="15">Top 4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="filter_link" data-href="country" data-value="16">EU</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="filter_link" data-href="country" data-value="17">Top 8</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="filter_link" data-href="country" data-value="18">Non EU</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="individual_link" data-href="country" data-value="25">Individual <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="individual_country" name="individual_country" style="font-size: 11px;  text-align: center; display: none;"/>
                        <div id="no-result" style="display: none;">No results found</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="top_sub_link">
                        <a href="#" class="filter_link" data-href="country" data-value="0" onclick="reset_filter('country');">Reset</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-nav"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>

var filters = ['country'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.btn_filter_category').on('click', function() {
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-href');
        show_filter(filter + '_filters');
        unselect_filters();
        $(this).find('.links_new.link_hover').removeClass('link_hover').addClass('link_hover_selected');
    });
    $(".filter_link").on('click', function() {
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-href');
        var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $('#filter_' + filter).val(value);
        $('#select_' + filter).val(0);
        $("#news_search_form").submit();
    });
    $(".individual_link").on('click', function() {
        var filter = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $(this).remove();
        $('#individual_' + filter).show();
    });

});

$(function () {
    var filter = 'country';
    var url = "{{ url('country/search/'.$lang) }}";
    $("#individual_" + filter).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    name: request.term
                },
                success: function(data){
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        // alert(item.label);
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.value     // EDIT
                        }
                    }));
                 }
            })
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#filter_' + filter).val(0);
            $('#select_' + filter).val(ui.item.value);
            $("#news_search_form").submit();
        }
    });
});
function unselect_filters() {
    $('div.links_new').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).removeClass('link_hover').removeClass('link_hover_selected').addClass('link_hover');
    });
}
function show_filter(selected_class) {
    var arrayLength = filters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var class_name = filters[i] + '_filters';
        if(selected_class != class_name) $('#'+ class_name).hide();
        else $('#'+ class_name).show();
    }
}
function reset_filter(filter) {
    $('#filter_' + filter).val(0);
    $('#select_' + filter).val(0);
    $("#news_search_form").submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution.
The autocomplete submit form is working fine. Unfortunately there was some redirect after the submit, which was causing and empty POST array.